# (Winapi C++) How to pass data from window to window without globals?

Tags: c++, winapi

I've tried to do research on this and I'm still very confused. I really don't want to use globals, but even on the msdn site they say "set this to global to access it from the dialog box callback". Is there someway I can create memory on the heap and pass a pointer to a newly created dialog box? I want the dialog box to be able to change the data that is accessed through the pointer.

Comment: I think it is possible though long data, but ...
It is probably a better idea you to rethink your strategy. Initializing the dialog in the begging and extracting the data at the end (DDT) is better way to go in 95% of the cases

Comment: how would I go about doing that? And you mean instead of passing a pointer in to the dialog and having the dialog edit that data, to create the data in dialog, and to get a pointer to it from the dialog?

Comment: It is hard to say from the info you provided. The idea is instead your dialog to works directly with the model (document) by pointer it to has internal model where to store the data temporarily. It will modify it there which will give you easy cancel option for example. Then when the dialog is done you will transfer the data back to the model. Most UI frameworks provide infrastructure for that.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using the `DialogBoxParam` you could pass the pointer in the `dwInitParam`:

```
DialogBoxParam(hInstance, 
               MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG), 
               hwndParent, 
               YourDialogFunc, 
               dwInitParam);
```

Then you would access the data from your dialog callback:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK YourDialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch(uMsg) [
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
      // the lParam parameter will contain the data sent through the dwInitParam
      return 1;
    break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you use the `CreateWindowEx` you would sent you data through the `lpCreateParams`in the `CREATESTRUCT` being sent through the `lpParam` parameter.

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(uMsg) [
      case WM_CREATE:
      {
        CREATESTRUCT *pCreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam);
        int* userdata = reinterpret_cast<int*>(pCreate->lpCreateParams);
        // store the pointer in the instance data of the window
        // so it could always be retrieved by using GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA) 
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)userdata);
      }
      break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
 }
```

Comment: This is the standard way to do it.

Comment: And the usual C++ technique is to pass `this` as that extra parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use "PostMessage" with WM_USER (or any message value >= WM_USER) to send custom data between windows. (SendWindow will also work, but it will have synchronous behavior and block until the receiving window has consumed the message).

As others have hinted in the comments to your post and in other answers, there may be a better way to accomplish what you are really trying to do. If you want to just associate some data or data object with a window handle, then the GWLP_USERDATA solution proposed by Krister is standard.

Typically PostMessage/SendMessage with custom message type and data is used for signaling something from another thread or from a non-UI component.

But here's some code to answer your original question:

```
// sending window calls this
BYTE* data = malloc(DATA_BLOCK_SIZE);
// not shown - initialize "data"
PostMessage(hwndOtherDialog, WM_USER, 0, (LPARAM)data);
```

To receive it, your WndProc (or DlgProc) for that window will get at it as follows:

```
LRESULT __stdcall WndProcOtherWindow(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    case WM_USER:
    {
        BYTE* data = (BYTE*)lParam;

        // not shown - process data

        free(data);
        return 0;
    }
```