# Save values in a std::vector from a Win32 API window procedure

Tags: c++, winapi

I am new to the Win32 API.  I have beginner questions.

How do I get and display values saved in a vector (`mynum`) in `wWinMain()`? How can I initialize it inside `wWinMain()`?.

1. I did it as a global variable, but there must be a better way.
2. I am using `DestroyWindow(hwnd);` inside the click event of a button, is this the correct way?

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

#define ID_EDIT 1
#define ID_BUTTON 2
    
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

std::vector<int>mynum; // I don't want to initilze it here//

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    
    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Edit control";
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wstringstream mg;
       
    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Edit control",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        220, 220, 280, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    mg<< L"Size: " << mynum.size()<<" 1:"<<mynum[0] << " 2: " << mynum[1];    
    int r= MessageBox(NULL, mg.str().c_str(), L"Erfolg", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    
    static HWND hwndEdit1, hwndEdit2;
    HWND hwndButton;
    
    switch (msg) {
    
        case WM_CREATE:
    
            hwndEdit1 = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", NULL,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER| ES_NUMBER,
                50, 50, 50, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT,
                NULL, NULL);
    
            hwndEdit2 = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", NULL,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_NUMBER,
                50, 80, 50, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT,
                NULL, NULL);
    
            hwndButton = CreateWindowW(L"button", L"Show vector",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 50, 120, 100, 25,
                hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);
    
            break;
    
        case WM_COMMAND:
    
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) {
    
              
                LONG num1 = GetWindowLong(hwndEdit1, GWL_STYLE);
                mynum.push_back(num1);
    
                LONG num2 = GetWindowLong(hwndEdit2, GWL_STYLE);
                mynum.push_back(num2);
    
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);  **// IS IT CORRECT? //**
                
            }
    
            break;
    
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
    
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Winapi C++) How to pass data from window to window without globals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761167/winapi-c-how-to-pass-data-from-window-to-window-without-globals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the `vector` as a local variable inside of `wWinMain()`, and then use the `lpParam` parameter of `CreateWindowW()` to pass a pointer to the `vector` into your window procedure, eg:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define ID_EDIT 1
#define ID_BUTTON 2

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Edit control";
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    vector<int> mynum;   

    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Edit control",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        220, 220, 280, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, &mynum);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    wostringstream mg;
    mg << L"Size: " << mynum.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mynum.size(); ++i) {
        mg << " " << (i+1) << ":" << mynum[i];
    }   

    int r = MessageBoxW(NULL, mg.str().c_str(), L"Erfolg", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    static HWND hwndEdit1, hwndEdit2, hwndButton;

    switch (msg) {

        case WM_CREATE: {

            CREATESTRUCT* pcs = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam);
            vector<int> *vec = static_cast<vector<int>*>(pcs->lpCreateParams);
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(vec));

            hwndEdit1 = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", NULL,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER| ES_NUMBER,
                50, 50, 50, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT,
                NULL, NULL);

            hwndEdit2 = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", NULL,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_NUMBER,
                50, 80, 50, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT,
                NULL, NULL);

            hwndButton = CreateWindowW(L"button", L"Show vector",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 50, 120, 100, 25,
                hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);

            break;
        }

        case WM_COMMAND:

            if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON && // or: reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lParam) == hwndButton
                HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) {

                vector<int> *vec = reinterpret_cast<vector<int>*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

                LONG num1 = GetWindowLong(hwndEdit1, GWL_STYLE);
                vec->push_back(num1);

                LONG num2 = GetWindowLong(hwndEdit2, GWL_STYLE);
                vec->push_back(num2);

                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            }

            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And yes, using `DestroyWindow()` is correct, see [Closing the Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/closing-the-window):

> The user can close an application window by clicking the Close button, or by using a keyboard shortcut such as ALT+F4. Any of these actions causes the window to receive a WM_CLOSE message. The WM_CLOSE message gives you an opportunity to prompt the user before closing the window. **If you really do want to close the window, call the DestroyWindow function.** Otherwise, simply return zero from the WM_CLOSE message, and the operating system will ignore the message and not destroy the window.

The alternative is to send the window a `WM_CLOSE` message and let `DefWindowProcW()` destroy the window for you:

> However, there is a shortcut in this case. Recall that DefWindowProc executes the default action for any window message. **In the case of WM_CLOSE, DefWindowProc automatically calls DestroyWindow.** That means if you ignore the WM_CLOSE message in your switch statement, the window is destroyed by default.

```cpp
//DestroyWindow(hwnd);
SendMessageW(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```